# How to print a function with prinf()?

Tags: c, gcc

So, i've this code, but i dont know how to print result of a function foo()

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int arr[]){
    int *sum = 0;
    int product = 1;
 
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(*arr); i++){
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(*arr); i++){
        product *= arr[i];
    }

    printf("%d\n", *sum);
    printf("%d\n", product);
}

int main(){
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    foo(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

i've been tried just to do printf(arr()); but it isn't workded, what i do incorectlly?

Comment: Explain why you have `int *sum` insteads of `int sum`.

Comment: What are you expecting from `sizeof(*arr)`? This will not work if you want to iterate over the entire array.

Comment: "It does not work" is not a problem description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `sum`in place of `*sum`.

```
int sum = 0;
printf("%d\n", sum);
```

It should work.

Comment: It doesn't work, actually. It will give wrong output, probably `10 24`, when correct would be `15 120`.